# Hashtag Multiple

Tags: java, loops, unique

I am trying to find the number of unique hashtags in a tweet inputted by a user. for example, if someone inputs "#one #seven #one purple green #red", it would show 3 unique hashtags that would be "#one, #seven, #red". In my code, I can do that to one tweet, but I cannot figure out how to input multiple tweets and find all the unique hashtags from them.

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.jmgibson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Tweet {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a tweet");
    String tweet = scanner.nextLine();
    Set<String> hashtags = getHashtags(tweet);      
    System.out.println(hashtags.toString());
}

public static Set<String> getHashtags(String tweet) {
    String[] words = tweet.split(" ");
    Set<String> hashtags = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.startsWith("#")) {
            hashtags.add(word);
        }
    }
    return hashtags;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I'll offer some suggestions:

1. In `main()`, you'll need a loop that asks for input and makes calls
   to `getHashtags()`.
2. Instead of creating a new `HashSet` inside of `getHashtags()`,
       create one in `main()` (outside of the loop), and pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

1.loop and get many tweet inputs
something like

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
 System.out.println("Please enter a tweet");
 String tweet[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

2.pass the tweetstring array instead of passing tweet string

3.loop through tweet array line by line and add tag if and only if not already added

```
    public static Set<String> getHashtags(String[] tweet) {
      Set<String> hashtags = new HashSet<String>();
    //loop of tweet array starts    

    String[] words = tweet[i].split(" ");//i is loop variable

        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.startsWith("#")) {
              //here add condition to check if  hashings already doesnt have the word
                hashtags.add(word);
            }
        }

    }

    //loop ends

return hashtags;
```

Comment: What do you mean by pass the tweetstring array?

Comment: you are passing single tweet,instead pass lots of tweets .this below post might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535017/passing-a-string-array-as-argument

Comment: you would still use the same Set<String> hashtags = getHashtags(tweet); but be aware tha you are passing the whole tweet array now,is wat i wanted to say

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop in your main to gather multiple inputs.

I would gather your inputs into one string in order to work with your already defined getHashtags.

Something like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a tweet");

String tweet = "";
while(!scanner.nextLine().equals("stop")){
      tweet += scanner.nextLine();
}
Set<String> hashtags = getHashtags(tweet);      
System.out.println(hashtags.toString());
```

}

So a loop and a `+=` should do the trick.